# Calculating point of intersection based on angle and speed

Tags: python, math, vector, performance, intersection

I have a vector consisting of a point, speed and direction. We will call this vector R. And another vector that only consists of a point and a speed. No direction. We will call this one T.
Now, what I am trying to do is to find the shortest intersection point of these two vectors. Since T has no direction, this is proving to be difficult. I was able to create a formula that works in CaRMetal but I can not get it working in python.
Can someone suggest a more efficient way to solve this problem? Or solve my existing formula for X?

Formula:

[image: Formula]
<sub>(source: [bja888.com](http://storage.bja888.com/formula.png))</sub>

Key:

[image: Definitions]
<sub>(source: [bja888.com](http://storage.bja888.com/keys.png))</sub>

Where o or k is the speed difference between vectors. R.speed / T.speed

Comment: We can't see the formula you posted or the key...

Comment: Fixed. The SO parser seems to choke when you put the image filename as part of the alt-text.

Comment: Google for "solve equations online", type in your formula, press solve for x and you're done :P

Comment: Is the speed of R always lower than that of T? Otherwise you have some cases when an intersection can never occur. Like if R is a car going south on a road and T a human running on the same road, but starts north of the car. The human will never intersect the path of the car.

Comment: @kigurai I ended up with a quadratic formula which doesn't have a always have solution

Comment: It would be helpful to clean up your definitions in your question.  "I have a vector consisting of a point, speed and direction" is nonsensical, at least to people accustomed to the traditional definition of a velocity vector, which doesn't involve position.  More accurate would be "I have a spatial position and velocity vector".

Answer (score 1):

My math could be a bit rusty, but try this:

*p* and *q* are the position vectors, *d* and *e* are the direction vectors. After time *t*, you want them to be at the same place:

**(1)** *p+t*d = q+t*e*

Since you want the direction vector *e*, write it like this

**(2)** *e = (p-q)/t + d*

Now you don't need the time *t*, which you can calculate using your speed constraint *s* (otherwise you could just travel to the other point directly):

The direction vector *e* has to be of the length *s*, so

**(3)** *e<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + e<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> = s<sup>2</sup>*

After some equation solving you end up with

**(4)**

**I)** *a = sum(p-q)/(s<sup>2</sup>-sum(d<sup>2</sup>))*

**II)** *b = 2*sum(d*(p-q))/(s<sup>2</sup>-sum(d<sup>2</sup>))*

**III)** *c = -1*

**IV)** *a + b*t + c*t<sup>2</sup> = 0*

The *sum* goes over your vector components (2 in 2d, 3 in 3d)

The last one is a quadratic formula which you should be able to solve on your own ;-)

Comment: I don't know about LaTeX, but HTML <sub> and <sup> might make it a bit more presentable...

Comment: Uhm, **(2)** doesn't follow **(1)** .. its `e = d + (p-q)/t`

Answer (score 0):

1. Let's assume that the first point,
   A, has zero speed. In this case, it
   should be very simple to find the
   direction which will give the
   fastest intersection.
2. Now, A **does** have a speed. We can force it to have zero speed by deducting it's speed vector from the vector of B. Now we can solve as we did in 1.

Just a rough idea that came to mind...

**Some more thoughts:**

If A is standing still, then the direction B need to travel in is directly towards A. This gives us the direction in the coordinate system in which A is standing still. Let's call it d.

Now we only need to convert the direction B needs to travel from the coordinate system in which A is still to the coordinate system in which A is moving at the given speed and direction, d2.

This is simply vector addition. d3 = d - d2
 We can now find the direction of d3.

**And a bit more formal:**

*A is stationary*:

Sb = speed of B, known, scalar

alpha = atan2( a_y-b_y, a_x-b_x )

Vb_x = Sb * cos(alpha)

Vb_y = Sb * sin(alpha)

*A moves at speed Sa, direction beta*:

Vb_x' = Sb * cos(alpha) + Sa * cos(beta)

Vb_y' = Sb * sin(alpha) + Sa * sin(beta)

alpha' = atan2( Vb_y', Vb_x' )

Haven't tested the above, but it looks reasonable at first glance...

Answer (score 0):

In nature hunters use the constant bearing decreasing range algorithm to catch prey.
I like the explanation of how bats do this [link text](http://www.plosbiology.org/article/info:doi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pbio.0040108)

We need to define a few more terms.

```
Point A         - the position associated with vector R.
Point B         - the position associated with vector T.
Vector AB    - the vector from point A to point B
Angle beta  - the angle between vector R and vector AB.
Angle theta - the angle between vector T and vector AB
```

The formula is usually given as

```
theta = asin( |R| * sin(beta) / |T| )
```

where

beta  = acos( AB.x*R.x + AB.y*R.y )

You don't want to use this directly, since asin and acos only return angles between -PI/2 to PI/2.

```
beta  = atan2( R.y, R.x  ) - atan2( AB.y, AB.x )
x        = |R| * sin(beta) / |T|
y        = 1 + sqrt( 1 - x*x )
theta = 2*atan2( y, x )
```

Of course if x > 1 R is too fast and intersection doesn't exist

EG

Answer (score -2):

OK, if I understand you right, you have

R = [ xy0, v, r ]
   T = [ xy1, v ]

If you are concerned about the shortest intersection point, this will be achieved when your positions are identical, and in an Euclidean space this also forces the direction of the second "thing" being perpendicular to the first. You can write down the equations for this and solve them easily.

Comment: If you have two objects that are traveling at different speeds and want to find the collission point I am quite sure that traveling perpendicular to each other will very very seldom produce the correct result. Maybe you are thinking of the closest distance between a point and a line which will be between the point and a point on the line such that the vector between them are perpendicular to the line?